# FittedBox not allowing to set specific font size

Tags: flutter, dart

I have used a FittedBox() for Text widget and the issue is I could not set font size of my choice. I have tried some specific font sizes but the font remains same. Here is the screenshot of UI I am talking about [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvjYT.png)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvjYT.png), highlighted with blue color.

This is the code snippet.

```html
 Container(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: 30),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
                    child: Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: Container(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            child: FittedBox(
                              fit: BoxFit.contain,
                              child:  Text(
                                  'Qty',
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),

                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          width: 10,
                          child: VerticalDivider(
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 2,
                          child: Container(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            // color: Colors.blue[200],
                            child: FittedBox(
                              fit: BoxFit.contain,
                              child: Text(
                                'Description',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  // fontSize: textSize,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          width: 10,
                          child: VerticalDivider(
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Container(
                            //width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.07,
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: FittedBox(
                              fit: BoxFit.contain,
                              child: Text(
                                'Price',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 12,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          width: 10,
                          child: VerticalDivider(
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Container(
                            // width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.07,
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: FittedBox(
                              fit: BoxFit.contain,
                              child: Text(
                                'Extend',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 12,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
```

I have also tried to reduce the widget height using BoxConstraints property but it is also not working. Anyone help me please to solve this issue.

Comment: Please remove `constraints` and `FittedBox` and try again.

Comment: This is how `BoxFit.contain,` literally works, it forces its child to be as large as possible while containing entirely within the parent box. What do you want it to be? As far as I see you dont need `BoxFit` and just need to set `alignment` property of a parent `Container`

Comment: Yes, it worked after removing FittedBox and constraints